# Where to install json-c

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, libraries

I'm working on a project, that requires the library "json-c". Now I want to install this lib according to the official site (https://github.com/json-c/json-c#buildunix), but, this may sound stupid, where should I install it / clone and build it ?
Should I install the lib in the working directory of the project or can i install it anywhere ?
I ask this question, because I'm new to Ubuntu and used to install libs via apt-get.

(The used Ubuntu Version is 20.4, running in a virtual box)
I'm sorry :)

Answer (score 10):

I suggest installing `libjson-c-dev` package instead of building it from source.

```
sudo apt install libjson-c-dev
```